# Should I host support forum on wordpress.org or my own website?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, pipe, forum

I have a Wordpress plugin WP Pipes hosted at http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-pipes/.

I see that it is convenience for users to ask question right in the support page at http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/wp-pipes, but it will be a pain when we have lots of topics in there.

Is there anyone here have experience about that? Should we offer support service right there in wordpress.org or host it in our own website?

Answer (score 1):

It is not a problem to give support on wp plugin site. Users always search support topics on wp plugin main page. If you want to do more specific support page to your plugin such as search functionality for your plugin to help returning user to search previous questions, you can use your own support system. I am using [FreshDesk](http://freshdesk.com/) to give support my users. You can create your own portal, manage tickets, and much more in this system. Users can search previously opened tickets in this portal. It has free plan also

Comment: You are right at the search problems using wp.org support forum, it's pain in the neck if we have lots of topics and want to find some existing topics. But provide support in parallel places will make users confusing, I think.

Comment: On freshdesk, this is my newly created support portal http://socialauth.freshdesk.com/support/home . You can analyze it